# Hot Patching A Function

Tags: c, winapi, assembly, reverse-engineering

I'm trying to hot patch an exe in memory, the source is available but I'm doing this for learning purposes. (so please no comments suggesting i modify the original source or use detours or any other libs)

Below are the functions I am having problems with.

```
vm_t* VM_Create( const char *module, intptr_t (*systemCalls)(intptr_t *), vmInterpret_t interpret )
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Oh snap! We hooked VM_Create!", L"Success!", MB_OK);
    return NULL;
}

void Hook_VM_Create(void)
{

    DWORD dwBackup;
    VirtualProtect((void*)0x00477C3E, 7, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwBackup);

    //Patch the original VM_Create to jump to our detoured one.
    BYTE *jmp = (BYTE*)malloc(5);
    uint32_t offset = 0x00477C3E - (uint32_t)&VM_Create; //find the offset of the original function from our own
    memset((void*)jmp, 0xE9, 1);
    memcpy((void*)(jmp+1), &offset, sizeof(offset));
    memcpy((void*)0x00477C3E, jmp, 5);

    free(jmp);
}
```

I have a function VM_Create that I want to be called instead of the original function. I have not yet written a trampoline so it crashes (as expected). However the message box does not popup that I have detoured the original VM create to my own. I believe it is the way I'm overwriting the original instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can see a few issues.

I assume that `0x00477C3E` is the address of the original `VM_Create` function. You really should not hard code this. Use `&VM_Create` instead. Of course this will mean that you need to use a different name for your replacement function.

The offset is calculated incorrectly. You have the sign wrong. What's more the offset is applied to the instruction pointer at the *end* of the instruction and not the beginning. So you need to shift it by 5 (the size of the instruction). The offset should be a signed integer also.

Ideally, if you take into account my first point the code would look like this:

```
int32_t offset = (int32_t)&New_VM_Create - ((int32_t)&VM_Create+5);
```

Thanks to Hans Passant for fixing my own silly sign error in the original version!

If you are working on a 64 bit machine you need to do your arithmetic in 64 bits and, once you have calculated the offset, truncate it to a 32 bit offset.

Another nuance is that you should reset the memory to being read-only after having written the new `JMP` instruction, and call [`FlushInstructionCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679350%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Okay, I've updated that my offset so that it is now correct. I didn't think of adding 5 it makes sense now. But I'm still not getting a window saying that we've branched off to my vm_create. I know the way I'm writing bytes to memory is UGLY, is there a neater way to do this? Do you see any problems with the way I'm writing to memory?

Comment: Did you remember to turn the sign around in offset. In your terminology the code should be: `int32_t offset = (int32_t)&VM_Create + 5 - (int32_t)0x00477C3E;`

Comment: The way you write to memory is fine. You should check the return value of `VirtualProtect` but if that did not work then you'd get a seg fault. You should pass 5 rather than 7 to `VirtualProtect`. Really, the only thing that can go wrong here is the calculation of the offset.

Comment: The sign is wrong.  Offset = &newFunc - (patchAddr + 5).  -5.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for that! I've fixed it now. Sometimes I wonder how I ever managed to get awarded not one but two degrees in mathematics!!  ;-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: FlushInstructionCache() doesn't do anything on x86/64. It's needed for ARM and likely Itanium. I don't think Windows cares much about the state of the application pages when the latter terminates. At least, not when they're still readable if they were readable originally.

Comment: @Alex You don't them to be writeable though. Of course it works if they are but ideally it's worth restoring that protection.

Comment: Okay, it's working perfectly now. I just have to write up my trampoline function now with the bytes I over write. And I understand the jump arithmetic perfectly now, the jmp instruction jumps relative from where it ends, not where the function begins (I knew this I don't know why I was thinking otherwise), so to calculate the offset we add 5 to the original vm_create, since the amount of data we wrote in for the jmp + relative address was 5 bytes. Thank you very much. And I did reset the memory to PAGE_EXECUTE_READ.

Comment: Glad you are happy. I love hooking like this. Get giddy on the power!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099660/writing-a-trampoline-function I'm having trouble again, mind lending your expert aid? Or should I struggle a little longer :P