# Writing a Trampoline Function

Tags: c, winapi, assembly, reverse-engineering

I have managed to overwrite the first few bytes of a function in memory and detour it to my own function. I'm now having problems creating a trampoline function to bounce control back over to the real function.

This is a second part to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8089887/hot-patching-a-function/8089958#8089958).

```
BYTE *buf = (BYTE*)VirtualAlloc(buf, 12, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
void (*ptr)(void) = (void (*)(void))buf;

vm_t* VM_Create( const char *module, intptr_t (*systemCalls)(intptr_t *), vmInterpret_t interpret )
{
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Oh Snap! VM_Create Hooked!", L"Success!", MB_OK);

    ptr();

    return NULL;//control should never get this far
}

void Hook_VM_Create(void)
{
    DWORD dwBackup;
    VirtualProtect((void*)0x00477C3E, 7, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &dwBackup);

    //save the original bytes
    memset(buf, 0x90, sizeof(buf));
    memcpy(buf, (void*)0x00477C3E, 7);

    //finish populating the buffer with the jump instructions to the original functions
    BYTE *jmp2 = (BYTE*)malloc(5);
    int32_t offset2 = ((int32_t)0x00477C3E+7) - ((int32_t)&buf+12);
    memset((void*)jmp2, 0xE9, 1);
    memcpy((void*)(jmp2+1), &offset2, sizeof(offset2));
    memcpy((void*)(buf+7), jmp2, 5);

    VirtualProtect((void*)0x00477C3E, 7, PAGE_EXECUTE_READ, &dwBackup);
}
```

0x00477C3E is the address of the function that has been overwritten. The asm for the original function are saved to `buf` before i over write them. Then my 5 byte jmp instruction is added to `buf` to return to the rest of the original function.

The problem arises when ptr() is called, the program crashes. When debugging the site it crashes at does not look like my `ptr()` function, however double checking my offset calculation looks correct.

NOTE: superfluous code is omitted to make reading through everything easier

EDIT: This is what the `ptr()` function looks like in ollydbg

```
0FFB0000   55               PUSH EBP
0FFB0001   57               PUSH EDI
0FFB0002   56               PUSH ESI
0FFB0003   53               PUSH EBX
0FFB0004   83EC 0C          SUB ESP,0C
0FFB0007  -E9 F1484EFD      JMP 0D4948FD
```

So it would appear as though my offset calculation is wrong.

Comment: Where do you overwrite the code at 0x00477C3E to jump to your VM_Create? Where do you restore the code at 0x00477C3E? Do you take any steps to preserve registers, etc. when returning to the original code?

Comment: The original VM_Create is overwritten at the beginning of VM_Hook_Create. The code is not restored, a detour function that contains the missing asm instructions is loaded into a buffer and then called, at the end of the buffer, a jump to the remainder of the original vm_create is 'called'(?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your buf[] ends up containing 2 things:

- 7 first bytes of the original instruction
- jmp

Then you transfer control to buf. Is it guaranteed that the first 7 bytes contain only whole instructions? If not, you can crash while or after executing the last, incomplete instruction beginning in those 7 bytes.

Is it guaranteed that the instructions in those 7 bytes do not do any EIP-relative calculations (this includes instructions with EIP-relative addressing such as jumps and calls primarily)? If not, continuation in the original function won't work properly and probably will end up crashing the program.

Does the original function take any parameters? If it does, simply doing `ptr();` will make that original code work with garbage taken from the registers and/or stack (depends on the calling convention) and can crash.

**EDIT**: One more thing. Use `buf+12` instead of `&buf+12`. In your code `buf` is a pointer, not array.

Comment: Yes, the first seven bytes are whole instructions. In fact, they are the first seven bytes you see in my ptr() function. The parameters of the original function are pushed on the stack, and no eip-relative calculations are being made. So everything should be valid.

Comment: @Adam: remove the ampersand before buf.

Comment: roflmao, omg I'm such an idiot. How the heck did i miss that. You would think with everything else going on with pointers a mistake like that wouldn't be made. tyvm

Comment: Calling ptr() was corrupting the stack, but fixed that and everything is going smoothly now :D