# redirecting a c function at runtime and calling the original function

Tags: c, linux, function, redirect, assembly

My program redirects a function to another function by writing a jmp instruction to the first few bytes of the function (only i386). It works like expected but it means that I can't call the original function anymore, because it will always jump to the new one.

There are two possible workarounds I could think of:

1. Create a new function, which overwrites the jmp instruction of the target function and call it. Afterwards the function writes back the jmp instruction.
   But I'm not sure how to pass the arguments since there can be any number of them. And I wonder if the target function can jmp somewhere else and skip writing back the jmp instruction (like throw catch?).
2. Create a new function which executes the code I have overwritten with the jmp instruction. But I can't be sure that the overwritten data is a complete instruction. I'd have to know how many bytes I have to copy for a complete instructions.

So, finally, my questions:

1. Is there another way I didn't think of?
2. How do I find the size of an instruction? I already looked at binutils and found [this](https://github.com/mirror/cygwin/blob/master/opcodes/i386-opc.tbl) but I don't know how to interpret it.

Here is a sample:

```
mov, 2, 0xa0, None, 1, Cpu64, D|W|CheckRegSize|No_sSuf|No_ldSuf, { Disp64|Unspecified|Byte|Word|Dword|Qword, Acc|Byte|Word|Dword|Qword }
```

the 2nd column shows the number of operands (2) and the last column has information about the operands, seperated by a comma

I also found this question which is pretty much the same but I can't be sure that the 7 bytes contain a whole instruction.
[Writing a Trampoline Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8099660/writing-a-trampoline-function)

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to do something that couldn't be done much simpler (and more portable) with a function pointer?

Comment: I have no conroll over the code which is calling the function, so, no. I can't do it with a function pointer.

Comment: Perhaps you should give more information to your problem so we can understand why you've chosen this solution. Then we can either help you with it or suggest something better.

Comment: I use hotpatch (https://github.com/vikasnkumar/hotpatch) to load a shared library in a running proccess and now I want to redirect a function the program uses to a function in the shared library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

Let's say this is the original function:

```
Instruction1
Instruction2
Instruction3
...
RET
```

convert it to this:

```
JMP new_stuff
old:
Instruction2
Instruction3
...
RET
...
new_stuff:
CMP call_my_function,0
JNZ my_function
Instruction1
JMP old
my_function:
...
```

Of course you'd have to take the size of the original instructions into account (you could find that out by disassembling with `objdump`, for example) so that the first `JMP` fits perfectly (pad with `NOP`s if the `JMP` is shorter than the original instruction(s)).

Comment: Thanks that helped. Getting the size of the original instruction seems the to be very hard. I can't use objdump because I had to know the name of the function or the address in the binary. The address in the proccess and in the binary may differ afaik.
edit: I tried to use libopcodes but I fail miserably.

Answer (score 1):

Sebastian, you can use the exe_load_symbols() function in hotpatch to get a list of the symbols and their location in the existing exe and then see if you can overwrite that in memory. I have not tried it yet. You may be able to do it with the LD_PRELOAD environment variable as well instead of hotpatch.

--Vikas